# Binary data with boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have this class with some binary data:

```
struct Message {
  int val1;
  double val2;
  std::string val3;    // contains some binary data
  template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & val1 & val2 & val3;
  }
};
```

How should I write archive function to handle this binary data in val3?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but aren't the default archive classes - for example, the text handler - capable of storing and retrieving binary data?

Comment: Probably not. I used a text archive here, and with some non-printable characters in string object. When I serialize and deserialize, I do not get the same data back. So, I must be missing something. There is a helper function boost::serialization::make_binary_object(), but I could not make it work. Also, I have not yet tried with binary serialization archives. So, probably these are the two options which I have, so I'll have to try these out today.

Comment: I've tried this using archive_text and it works just fine for a std::string containing all chars from (char)0 to (char)255. Are there any errors you are getting? Which platform are you using? What characters in the std::string are not correctly serialized?

Comment: You are actually right. I checked this now and it works just fine. The problem was with my handler code only. Sorry for wasting your time.